# как поместить пароль администратора в bat , чтобы он не запрашивался?

Tags: cmd

Как кто можно сделать бат файл запускающий приложение с правами администратора? Главное чтобы не приходилось вводить пароль с клавиатуры. Нужен аналог runus но без ввода пароля. Пароль явно вписать в bat. Потом я его сконвертирую в exe и пароль видно не будет. Или тут нужно язык программирования по серьезней чем командный файл.?

Comment: А как вы собираетесь конвертировать bat в exe?

Comment: Чтобы не было видно пароль, его нужно, как минимум, зашифровать.

Comment: Конвертор bat в exe планирую использовать.

Comment: Если включить логику, то решение выглядит как "защита от дурака". Bat - это инструмент вызова **командной строки**. Таким образом, значение пароля будет так или иначе использоваться при вызове внешней команды, куда и будет передано значение пароля. Для отслеживания вызываемых процессов и параметров их командных строк не нужны спецутилиты. Достаточно широкораспространненных: **"Process explorer"**, **"Process Monitor"**  и других, даже встроенных средств аудита. То есть, получить значение пароля  при выборе такого решение - очень **простая** задача.